# How to display a json data in a tree model using knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a simple json file like this.

```
 "Test":
    [
        {
            "id":"1",
            "type" : "test1"
        },
        {
            "id":"1.1",     
            "type":"test2"
        },
        {
            "id":"1.1.1",
            "type":"test3"
        },
        {
            "id":"1.1.2",
            "type":"test3"                
        }]
```

I want to display this data in a tree model using knockout as like below.

```
      1 test1
      1.1  test2
         1.1.1  test3          
         1.1.2 test4
```

I haven't seen any sample solution for my requirement. anybody can guide me? Thank you.

Comment: you will have to convert your array to a tree structure. Basically write plain old JavaScript to do that and then it is easy with knockout to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is properly sorted then you can use `style` binding to apply left padding for item element via according CSS-rule:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: test">
    <li data-bind="style: { paddingLeft: (id.length * 10) + 'px' }">
        <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: type"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can check how it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/7vyfW/

This method **does not** track your structure, so it is useless if you want to create an editable list. But it is simple and effective if your task is just to display a tree.

Comment: Thank you. It is so simple :) I failed to think in this way :( But List style is not working.

Comment: Yes, if `id` is observable then you should use `id().length`.