# Tree like structure with single dimension array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have single dimension array {1, 2, 3, 4.. } where 4 is child of 3, 3 is child of 2 and so-on. I need to display the elements as tree view structure using knockout js. Is it possible to do it without creating parent-child array structure?

Comment: Why do you not want to have a parent-child array structure? If conceptually you have parents and children, I think the viewmodels should reflect this.

Comment: I have an array without parent-child structure. To create parent child relationship, I would need to iterate through the entire array again, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: You could use computed observables and display each element differently based on its position in the array, but this would still require iterating through the array once. I don't think you can get away with no iteration.

Comment: Hi pax, I understand that there will at least one iteration (knockout foreach binding). This cannot be avoided. However, when we know that next array element is child of current array element, can't we use this information to avoid an extra iteration. If there is no way, I can definitely take the known root.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eF5VL/

The core of the solution is function `childrenOf` that filters plain array of items and returs only children of specified parent. Note that this function also may be `ko.computed` if you plain array is observable and the subject to change.

```
var viewModel = {
    items: [
        { id: 1, parent: 0, name: "item 1" },
        { id: 2, parent: 0, name: "item 2" },
        { id: 3, parent: 2, name: "item 2.1" },
        { id: 4, parent: 2, name: "item 2.2" },
        { id: 5, parent: 0, name: "item 3" },
        { id: 6, parent: 5, name: "item 3.1" },
        { id: 7, parent: 6, name: "item 3.1.1" },
        { id: 8, parent: 0, name: "item 4" }
    ],
    childrenOf: function(parent){
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(
            viewModel.items,
            function(item){ return item.parent == parent; }
        );
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Markup:

```
<script id="tree_item" type="text/html">
    <li><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tree_item', foreach: $root.childrenOf(id) }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tree_item', foreach: childrenOf(0) }"></ul>
```

Markup also is clear and simple: just one template for every tree item.

**UPDATE:**

If you are sure that your items are properly sorted you may use another solution as I had answered here: [How to display a json data in a tree model using knockout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239401/how-to-display-a-json-data-in-a-tree-model-using-knockout/16242163)

You only should preprocess your items once to define level of nesting for every item.